# Oracle SQL - Summing a time series partition based on month

Tags: sql, oracle, automation, window

I am working with a data set that looks like this:

```
MTD       | ID | Active
-----------------------
01-APR-16 | A  | y
01-MAY-16 | A  | y
01-JUN-16 | A  | n
01-JUL-16 | A  | y
01-AUG-16 | A  | n
01-APR-16 | B  | n
01-MAY-16 | B  | y
01-JUN-16 | B  | y
01-JUL-16 | B  | y
01-AUG-16 | B  | y
```

I would like to add a count column to the data set that counts the number of times an ID has been active ('y') AFTER the current MTD. The desired output is:

```
MTD       | ID | Active | COUNT
-------------------------------
01-APR-16 | A  | y      | 2
01-MAY-16 | A  | y      | 1
01-JUN-16 | A  | n      | 1
01-JUL-16 | A  | y      | 0
01-AUG-16 | A  | n      | 0
01-APR-16 | B  | n      | 4
01-MAY-16 | B  | y      | 3
01-JUN-16 | B  | y      | 2
01-JUL-16 | B  | y      | 1
01-AUG-16 | B  | y      | 0
```

The query I am thinking of is:

```
SELECT 
 MTD,

 ID, 

 ACTIVE,

 SUM(CASE WHEN MTD > (current records MTD) 
          AND ACTIVE = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY ID) 
   as COUNT
```

I'm not sure how to compare each record's MTD to the current record's MTD in the window sum. How can I amend the first line of the case statement?

Thank you,

Ryan Barker

Comment: perhaps just `order by MTD desc` within the over after the ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `count() over()` with a `range` specification so you look at the rows following the current row (for each id) for an active flag `y` and only count them. This assumes `mtd` is a `date` column for the ordering to work.

```
SELECT 
 MTD,
 ID, 
 ACTIVE,
 COUNT(case when active='y' then 1 end) OVER(partition by ID order by mtd range between 1 following and unbounded following)
FROM your_table
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/ZGMI26428)**

Comment: I did not realize the following keyword existed. That is super useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you want to sum the number of rows with a "y" in reverse.  Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       greatest(sum(case when active = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by mtd desc) - 1,
                0)
from t;
```

Your idea is quite close.  You just need an `order by` in the partitioning clause.

Comment: I'd like to sum all "y"'s after the current month. This is close, but not quite there. If I have n, y, n, y, y as my ACTIVE column, your query returns the counts 2, 2, 1, 1, 0. The counts I am looking for is 3, 2, 2, 1, 0.

Comment: @RyanBarker . . . I don't see how to resolve the counts in your comment with the counts in the question.  Your use of MTD doesn't really help.  I'm not sure what this means in this context.

Comment: Hi Gordon, sorry I should have been clearer. MTD = Month to date. It is the value representing when the record occurred. I am looking to count the number of times active = 'y' after the record occurred. See vkp's solution: By saying range between 1 following and unbounded following and ordering by MTD in the partition, you are only considering from 1 MTD later than the current record to the end of the data set only when you do the count. Does that make sense?